# WP_Query attachments by multiple IDs

Tags: wp-query

I would like to get 2 images in media by their IDs. If I want to get only one image I would use this code

```
$args = array(
    'p' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_status' => 'any'
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

How can I do it for 2 images, without double queries?

It would be great if I can pass an array with IDs but `'p'` according to Codex can be only integer

```
    'p' => array(1,2),
```

[p (int) - use post id. Default post type is post.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `post__in` . The code will be something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array( 1, 2 ),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post_status' => 'any'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```